# Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile)

Tags: intellij-idea, scala-maven-plugin

I am trying to test on **Intellij IDEA** a [scala maven project](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector)

when i run

mvn test

i get this error :

```
 Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile) on project neo4j-spark-connector: Execution scala-compile of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
```

this is the [pom.xml](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/blob/master/pom.xml) i just added this dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>neo4j-contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-spark-connector</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0-M4</version>
 </dependency>
```

and this is the error logs :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven- plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile) on project neo4j-spark-connector:   Execution scala-compile of goal net.alchim31.maven:scal
a-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}:  The groupId cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute   goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile) on  project neo4j-spark-connector: Execution scala-compile of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution scala-compile of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}:
The groupId cannot be empty.
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.validateIdentity (DefaultArtifact.java:131)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init> (DefaultArtifact.java:124)
at org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem.createArtifactX (MavenRepositorySystem.java:565)
at org.apache.maven.bridge.MavenRepositorySystem.createArtifactX (MavenRepositorySystem.java:524)
```

.....
this what i can post from error logs the site don't allow more
How to fix it ?

Comment: can you provide the full log (from run on console) and the pom.xml ?

Comment: @DavidBernard I have edited my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the same issue as mine  [here](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/issues/224) , so i upgraded the **maven-scala-plugin** to 3.3.3 instead of 3.2.0, the previous error is disappeared

Comment: FYI the latest version of scala-maven-plugin is 3.4.2 (release today).

Comment: Please note that one may need to upgrade the maven version as well along with that as old maven versions are not compatible with higher versions of this plugin

Answer (score 3):

1. upgrade the version scala-maven-plugin to 3.4.2 if you're using a recent version of maven (like 3.5) because changes were made on dependeny management of maven.
2. change the scope of scala-library dependency from provided to "compile" (or remove the scope). It's possible that "provided" scope generate trouble for "mvn test" (tbh I don't remember if provided are available in test)
3. if you use the pom.xml of neo4j-spark-connector, I guess you try to compile neo4j-spark-connector, so why do you add itself as a dependency ? it could be the cause of your trouble (A depends of A)

Answer (score 2):

I was also having the same issue and what I found is:
sometimes it is coming because of compilation errors also specifically when you are using intellij idea.